# dual cone and functionals

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following set: $$ K^* := \{ x^* \in R^m | \forall k \in K  \ x^*(k) \geq 0 \}$$ K is an convex cone.

If $ y^* \in int K^*$, how can I see, that $y^*_i>0 $ ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $x^{*}(k)$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: I mean $(x^*)^T k \geq 0$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If $y^{*} \in \mbox{int} K$, and $y^{*}_{i}=0$, will there be points near $y^{*}$  and a vector $x^{*}$ such that $x^{*}y^{*}<0$?

Comment: You consider two elements of $K^*$ ?

Comment: Sorry, call the second vector $x$.  It's in $K$.  What do you know about the cone $K$?

Comment: Note that this simply isn't true for all cones $K$ in $R^{n}$ and their duals, so there's something missing from your problem statement.

Comment: But there is nothing missing. What do I have to add to my statement?

Comment: Try for example $K=\left\{x \in R^{2} | x=\alpha (1,1), \alpha \geq 0 \right \}$.  Then $K^{*}=\left\{ y \in R^{2} | y_{1}+y_{2} \geq 0 \right\}$, and $K^{*}$ includes interior points with $y_{1} < 0$ and other points with $y_{2} < 0$.  It is true if $K=R^{n}_{+}$, then $K^{*}=K$.